# Dúvida sobre tipos genéricos em TypeScript

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, typescript, classes, genéricos, typeorm

Estou estudando atualmente o TypeORM, e queria criar um controller genérico, pois sempre serão as mesmas operações CRUD. Sei que posso resolver com soluções nativas do TypeORM, como por exemplo o `getRepository()`, inclusive já até resolvi, porém agora quero tirar essa dúvida que persiste...

Então, no modo que tentei anteriormente, minhas entidades estão estendendo a classe `BaseEntity`, para poder ter acesso ao método `getRepository()` diretamente na classe. Assim:

```
export abstract class AbstractEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({default: true})
    ativo: boolean;

    @CreateDateColumn()
    createdAt: string;

    @UpdateDateColumn({ type: "timestamp" })
    updatedAt: number;
}
```

E essa classe somente para exemplificar:

```
export class Pessoa extends AbstractEntity {
    @Column()
    nome: string;
}
```

Eu esperava criar um controller genérico mais ou menos assim:

```
class GenericController<T extends BaseEntity> {
        async getAll(request: Request, response: Response, nextFunction: NextFunction) {
            return await T.getRepository().find();
        }
    }
```

Para utilizar assim:

```
export default class PessoaRoute {
    pessoaController = new GenericController<Pessoa>()

    constructor() {
        this.initializeRoutes();
    }

    initializeRoutes() {
        this.router.get('/', this.pessoaController.getAll);
    }
}
```

O problema que tenho é que no `GenericController` não tenho acesso aos métodos que preciso por meio do `T`, nem sequer ele é reconhecido como existente no TypeScript, isso naquele modo em que pretendo usar: `T.getRepository()`.

Li um pouco na documentação do TypeScript mas não compreendi o motivo de isso não ter dado certo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema que você está enfrentando resume-se em: o genérico **nunca** é um valor, mas sim um tipo. Desse modo, você não pode usá-lo como um valor.

Veja, no seu código, você está fazendo isso:

> ```
> return await T.getRepository().find();
> ```

Percebe? Você está tratando o tipo genérico `T` como se fosse um valor, o que ele não é.

Desse modo, o que você precisa fazer é aceitar o objeto `Pessoa` como argumento da classe (provavelmente no construtor). Algo assim:

```
class GenericController<T extends Entity> {
  constructor(private model: T) { }

  async getAll(/* Seus parâmetros aqui... */) {
    return this.model.getRepository().find();
  }
}
```

Note que agora estamos usando `this.model`, que é um valor com o tipo `T`.

Em seguida, para usar, basta fazer isso:

```
export default class PessoaRoute {
  pessoaController = new GenericController(Pessoa);

  // ...
}
```

Note que nem é necessário passar o genérico explicitamente em `GenericController`, uma vez que o TypeScript irá inferir o tipo automaticamente.

---

Não tem muito a ver com a pergunta, mas perceba que eu removi o `await` do `return await`. Naquela situação, o `return await` é alto redundante. O próprio `async` naquela função também não é necessário, mas para torná-la explicitamente assíncrona, é uma boa prática deixá-lo lá. :)